# Adding geometries to data layer - how to set feature styles during add?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm building a school layer.  For each school, I will assign a different icon depending on its properties.

This is my current solution.  I first insert all the schools into a data layer, and then run a `forEach` function to change each point's icon.  This is not optimal, because I am adding the schools, then immediately editing the schools.

```
// Current solution.  It is WORKING but it is not optimal

schools = (a list of google.maps.Data.Point objects)

for (school in schools) {
    schoolLayer.add({
        geometry: school,
    });
}

schoolLayer.forEach(function(feature) {
    schoolLayer.overrideStyle(feature, {
        if (some condition) {
            icon: ...
        } else {
            icon: ...
        }
    }
}
```

---

The optimal solution would be to add styles to the school while it is added, so that no editing is required afterwards.  Something like this:

```
// The solution I am trying to achieve.  The `StyleOptions` property is made up to represent what I am trying to achieve.  I want to add styles to the school as it is being inserted into the data layer

for (school in schools) {
    schoolLayer.add({
        geometry: school,
        StyleOptions: {
            if (some condition) {
                icon: ...
            } else {
                icon: ...
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The above code does not work.  Is there something I'm missing from the documentation that allows me to achieve that?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: @geocodezip Okay.  I removed as much code as I can without missing the point.

Comment: It still doesn't work. How can I reproduce the issue?

Comment: @geocodezip Which block of code are you looking at?  The first block of code works fine but it is not an optimal solution.  The second block is the solution I am trying to achieve, I made up `StyleOptions` as a property.  I rewrote the question to make it more clear.

Comment: It looks somewhat more reasonable now, but until I get time to try to make it work, I can't help.  A [mcve] would shorten that time, but, I am traveling now, so it will be a while in any case.

Comment: @geocodezip Okay.  Either way I appreciate your time.

Comment: What does your "list of google.maps.Data.Point objects" look like?

Comment: @geocodezip They could be any `Point` objects.  Sorry should've clarified that in question.  xomena provided a good solution.  Thanks for following up though, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest creating a list of `google.maps.Data.Feature` objects instead of the `google.maps.Data.Point` objects. `Data.Feature` can include geometry that is an instance of `google.maps.Data.Point` in your case, id that can be string or number and properties where you can put name-value pairs.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3/data#Data.Feature

The presence of properties in a feature makes a trick. You can apply a styling function for your data layer that reads property of the feature (icon in your case) and returns corresponding style. The styling function will be applied when you add a feature to the data layer.

Have a look at the following code sample, the `schoolLayer.setStyle()` is the most relevant part

```js
var map;
function initMap() {
  var schools = [
      new google.maps.Data.Feature({
        geometry: new google.maps.Data.Point({lat: 41.384301, lng: 2.173792}),
        id: 1,
        properties: {
          "icon": "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/blu-blank.png"
        }
      }),
      new google.maps.Data.Feature({
        geometry: new google.maps.Data.Point({lat: 41.384897, lng: 2.176656}),
        id: 2,
        properties: {
          "icon": "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/pink-blank.png"
        }
      }),
      new google.maps.Data.Feature({
        geometry: new google.maps.Data.Point({lat: 41.386756, lng: 2.175268}),
        id: 3,
        properties: {
          "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png"
        }
      })
  ];

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 17,
    center: {lat: 41.385064, lng: 2.173403}
  });

  var schoolLayer = map.data;
  schoolLayer.setStyle(function(feature){
    return {
        icon: feature.getProperty("icon"),
        title: "" + feature.getId()
    };
  });

  for (school of schools) {
    schoolLayer.add(school);
  }
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDztlrk_3CnzGHo7CFvLFqE_2bUKEq1JEU&callback=initMap">
```

You can also find this example on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xomena/tLsjkowp/

I hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah that works great.  Now I no longer need to do the `ForEach` function.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@xonema - Great answer.
Just adding that I set the properties locally in this manner:

```
new google.maps.Data.Feature({
       geometry: new google.maps.Data.Point(gaugeLatLng),
       properties: {
         title: gaugeDetail.gaugeId,
         icon: {
           path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
           scale: 6,
        },
}
})
```